# Guriddo jqGrid v5.3.0 on Bootstrap 4 and Font Awesome Icons

Tags: jqgrid

Checking if the latest version of Guriddo jqGrid v5.3.0 is the right fit for me. Due to the fact that Bootstrap 4 doesn't have glyphicons anymore, is it possible to use Font Awesome Icons with the jqGrid v5.3.0? If yes, can someone provide a sample code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The current release of Guriddo jqGrid 5.3 support Octicons and Iconic icon sets, which are officially recommended from Bootstrap . We plan to support Font Awesome in the next bug fix release

Comment: Is there an example on how to use Octicons and Iconic icon sets? Should it be downloaded separably? How to integrated it?

Comment: Here is [example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/bootstrap/functionality/bootstrap4/) of using Octicons. It is needed to use the appropriate css. Two options need to be set iconSet and styleUI which in this case is Bootstrap4

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
$.jgrid.defaults.styleUI = 'Bootstrap4';
$.jgrid.defaults.iconSet = "Iconic";
$.jgrid.defaults.iconSet = "fontAwesome";
```

Before:

$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({...