# jqgrid js with bootstrap4, octicons. subgrid icon location

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid js v5.3.2 with BS4, iconset set to octicons. See below [image] , should the subgrid icon/arrow be in the middle of the cell vertically? also, the expanded icon(the cell below) doesn't look as good as jqgrid BS3's, can we change this too?

Comment: @antfuentes87 please be careful when downvoting unless you're sure about the nature of the question.

Comment: Huh? I down voted because you shared no code? And for anyone to even attempt to fix this (unless they know the answer already) is going to want code?

Answer (score 0):

BS4 vertically align content of td at top, I added

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-btable .ui-sgcollapsed {
vertical-align: middle !important;
```

}

in mysite.css. For icon-open of subgrid, I'd expect a font awesome version of jqgrid.

Comment: Not sure that I understand the question(problem) - Guriddo jqGrid support font Awesome, but as per your question you use octicons?!?

Comment: @TonyTomov I was referring an example you provided here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488132/guriddo-jqgrid-v5-3-0-on-bootstrap-4-and-font-awesome-icons). After I set $.jgrid.defaults.iconSet = "fontAwesome", no icon is showing on subgrid icon cell. I know my font awesome setup works (for the project) and octicon works, is there a directory/path or FA version requirement for jqgrid using FA, or there is an example? Thx

Comment: Yes, the OP is for Octicons. but if FA works(it didn't for me on jqgrid), I'd like to switch to FA.